# Crosstabulate and summarize factors by another shared factor

Tags: r

Given data:

`D = data.frame(f1=c("a","a","b","b","b"), f2=c("X","Y","X","Y","Z"), val=1:5)`

```
D
  f1 f2 val
1  a  X   1
2  a  Y   2
3  b  X   3
4  b  Y   4
5  b  Z   5
```

How to crosstabulate `f2`pairs so that each element of the table corresponds to the sum of `val` for each pair of `f2` where they share the same `f1`?

```
# desired result (matrix diagonal could be either NA or 0):
   X   Y   Z
X NA  10   8
Y 10  NA   9
Z  8   9  NA
```

For example, `X` and `Y` share `a`, therefore `(1 + 2)` and also share `b` therefore `(3 + 4)`. Therefore `result[1, 2] = (1 + 2) + (3 + 4) = 10`. Also, `result[2, 3] = 4 + 5 = 9`, etc.

It helps to think of `f1` as stocks, `f2` as portfolios and `val` as invested holding amounts of each stock in each portfolio. The resulting table thus represents "herding" - the degree to which different portfolios tend to hold the same stock.

Is there any "smart" `R` function similar to `table` or `sweep` suitable for the task?

Comment: Since there has been multiple answers posted in short time frame, the one with the most votes will be accepted. Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found solution using cartesian self-join in `data.table` package and `dcast`ing the table of pairwise sums:

```
library(data.table)
D = data.table(f1=factor(c("a","a","b","b","b")), f2=factor(c("X","Y","X","Y","Z")), val=1:5)

setkey(D, f1)

DD = D[D, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
DD[, pair_sum := val + i.val]
DD[f2==i.f2, pair_sum := NA_real_]
dcast.data.table(DD, f2 ~ i.f2, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var="pair_sum")
#    f2  X  Y  Z
# 1:  X NA 10  8
# 2:  Y 10 NA  9
# 3:  Z  8  9 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty specific operation.  Probably just write your own function.  For example:

```
ff<-function(x,y){
   if(x==y)
       return(NA)
   f1vals<-intersect(D$f1[D$f2==x],D$f1[D$f2==y])
   sum(D$val[D$f1 %in% f1vals & D$f2 %in% c(x,y)])
 }
outer(unique(D$f2),unique(D$f2),Vectorize(ff))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   10    8
#[2,]   10   NA    9
#[3,]    8    9   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base` solution could be something like:

```
m<-subset(merge(D,D,"f1"),f2.x!=f2.y)
m<-aggregate(val.x~f2.x+f2.y,data=m,sum)
m<-xtabs(val.x~f2.x+f2.y, data=m)
m+t(m)
    f2.x
f2.y  X  Y  Z
   X  0 10  8
   Y 10  0  9
   Z  8  9  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
outdf = data.frame(name1="", name2="", value=0, stringsAsFactors=F)
for(i in 2:(ncol(dd)-1)) for(j in (i+1):ncol(dd)) {
    tdd = dd[c(i,j)]
    tdd = tdd[complete.cases(tdd),]
    mysum=  sum(stack(tdd)$values)
    outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,] = c(names(dd)[i], names(dd)[j], mysum)
}
outdf[-1,]
  name1 name2 value
2     X     Y    10
3     X     Z     8
4     Y     Z     9
```